# Unit тестирование представления, в форме которого присутствует поле ManyToManyField

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, юнит-тесты, тестирование

Тестирую представление на создание нового апартамента.

```
resp = self.client.post(
        reverse('building:create_apartment'),
        {
            "buildings_exit": BuildingsExit.objects.filter(
                                Q(pk__gte=2147000000) &
                                Q(pk__lte=2147000001)),
            "number": 999,
            "apartment_type": 15,
            "owner": owner_query2})
self.assertTrue(resp.context['form'].is_valid())
```

Поле owner тоже ManyToManyField, но рассматривать не будем, ибо ситуация та же самая что и с buildings_exit. Будем рассматривать ситуацию с buildings_exit.

Модель Apartment:

```
class Apartment(models.OurModel):
apartment_number_re = r"^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}$"

update_url = 'building:apartment_update'
create_url = 'building:apartment_create'

apartment_type = (
    (3, 'Квартира'),
    (6, 'Офис'),
    (9, 'Магазин'),
    (12, 'Сервис'),
    (15, 'Склад'),
    (18, 'Парковка'),
    (21, 'Гараж'),
    (-11, 'Другое'),
)

buildings_exit = models.ManyToManyField(
                        BuildingsExit,
                        through='ThroughApartmentBuildingsexit',
                        through_fields=('through_apartment', 'through_buildings_exit'),
                        verbose_name="Выходы здания")
number = models.SmallIntegerField(
    validators=[
        validators.RegexValidator(
            regex=apartment_number_re,
            message='Неверный формат номера квартиры.',
            code='invalid_apartment_number'
        )
    ],
    verbose_name="Номер квартиры"
)
apartment_type = models.IntegerField(
                    choices=apartment_type,
                    verbose_name="Тип апартамента")
owner = models.ManyToManyField(
                        Owner,
                        db_table='building_apartment-owner',
                        blank=True,
                        verbose_name="Владельцы недвижимости")

class Meta:
    app_label = 'building'
    verbose_name = "Апартамент"
    verbose_name_plural = "Апартаменты"

def __str__(self):
    if self.number:
        return f"{self.apartment_type} {self.number}"
    else:
        return f"{self.apartment_type}"
```

Промежуточная модель для связи многие ко многим к полю buildings_exit:

```
class ThroughApartmentBuildingsexit(models.OurModel):
through_apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
through_buildings_exit = models.ForeignKey(BuildingsExit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='objectid', db_constraint=False)

class Meta:
    app_label = 'building'
    db_table = 'building_through_apartment-buildings_exit'
```

Модель BuildingsExit:

```
class BuildingsExit(models.OurModelForArcgis):
update_url = 'building:buildings_exit_update'
# create_url = нет

objectid = models.IntegerField(
    unique=True,
    primary_key=True
    )
shape = models.TextField(
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    verbose_name="Геометрия")  # This field type is a guess.
name = models.CharField(
    max_length=50,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    verbose_name="Название")
exit_type = models.SmallIntegerField(
    verbose_name="Тип выхода",
    choices=dm.get_domains_as_tuple("buildings_exit_type"))
building_segment = models.ForeignKey(
    BuildingSegment,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    verbose_name="Сегмент здания")

globalid = models.CharField(max_length=38)
created_user = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
last_edited_user = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
last_edited_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
gdb_branch_id = models.IntegerField()
gdb_from_date = models.DateTimeField()
gdb_is_delete = models.SmallIntegerField()
gdb_deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
gdb_deleted_by = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
gdb_archive_oid = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

class Meta:
    app_label = 'building'
    managed = False
    db_table = 'buildingsexit'
    verbose_name = "Выход здания"
    verbose_name_plural = "Выходы здания"
    unique_together = (
        ('globalid', 'gdb_branch_id', 'gdb_from_date'),
        ('gdb_branch_id', 'gdb_from_date', 'objectid'),
        ('gdb_branch_id', 'gdb_from_date', 'gdb_is_delete', 'objectid'),)

@property
def get_apartments(self):
    """Возвращает все апартаменты, которые
    относятся к этому выходу, в виде объекта QuerySet.
    """
    return self.apartment_set.all()

def __str__(self):
    if self.name:
        return self.name
    else:
        return str(self.objectid)
```

В чем проблема: при тестировании если у передаваемых в тестировании представления объектов buildings_exit указано поле name, то следовательно и **str** этого объекта будет выводить объект по имени. Если не указать name, то **str** выводит его objectid (который является первичным ключом). Теперь. Если в **str** выводит объект по имени, то поле buildins_exit формы не проходит валидацию, и, следовательно, тестирование проваливается. Если не задать поле name у передаваемого объекта buildings_exit, то почему-то форма оказывается валидной. Если я в качестве **str** укажу просто для каждого объекта выдавать один из objectid (pk), то именно этот объект попадёт в cleaned_data, а остальные нет. Причем в словарь data формы (где все поля прописаны) при client.post запросе в тестировании попадают все переданные buildings_exit

Вопросы:

1)почему при работе из браузера **str** не влияет и всё успешно, но при тестировании подключается **str** и в недрах django что-то влияет на валидацию поля buildins_exit?

2) следует из первого: как это починить? При тестировании я передаю в поле QuerySet, может быть django при работе из браузера передаёт не QuerySet, а нечто иное (что тогда?).

3) выделенные жирным слова str представляют собой питоновский метод для отображения объекта, но сайт съел по два нижних подчеркивания до и после слова. Прочитал справку и не нашёл как заэкранировать, чтобы они показывались. Подскажите как это сделать.

Python 3.7.2, django.VERSION:(2, 2, 1, 'final', 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась передачей в buildings_exit поле тестирования не QuerySet, а списка, который содержит pk объектов, к примеру:

```
[buildings_exit1.pk, buildings_exit2.pk]
```